# Charging supercapacitor parallel with different sources

Tags: charging, supercapacitor, capacitor-charging

Is it possible to charge one supercapacitor with multi voltage sources in same time? All rated at near by 4V for example, 4.05, 4.1, 4.0 volts.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of.

By definition, the terminal voltage of the capacitor is zero when you start charging it and rises asymptotically. So if you simply connect three voltage sources to it through diodes, it will potentially draw power from all three according to their source impedances.

However, as it gets close to 4.0V it can no longer charge from that source, and the final rise to 4.1V will be powered entirely from the 4.1V source.

Comment: What source impedance cause in here? What if impedance of all sources equal or very far from each other?

Comment: All real voltage sources have some source impedance. If some of the sources have a high source impedance, it's hard to draw much power from them and more power will be drawn from the lower-impedance sources.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. How can I select diodes for best efficiency?

Comment: Schottky. Size according to how much current you expect.

Comment: There are so-called "ideal diodes" (which are basically MOSFET transistors), e.g. http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4358